# How to stack fcm push notification and display it when internet gets on , Flutter firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, background-service

I am using fcm for push notification , and i am trying to stack the notifications when the internet is off ,

What is happening now is

- When the app doesn't have internet and the app if receives more than one notification , when the interent is switched on , only the latest notification is shown.

What I want to achieve is

- When the app doesn't have internet and the app if receives more than one notification , when the interent is switched on , I want to show all the notifications not just the latest one.

I am presently using the following code snippets.

```
 // Background and also terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((value) =>
        Navigator.push(
            context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DummyScreen())));

    // Background not terminated
    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      print(
          "The message from within the onMessageOpenedApp and i am within the home_page is : " +
              message.notification!.title.toString());
      Navigator.push(
          context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => DummyScreen()));
    });

   // When app is in foreground
   FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      if (notification != null && android != null && !kIsWeb) {
        flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.show(
          notification.hashCode,
          notification.title,
          notification.body,
          NotificationDetails(
            android: AndroidNotificationDetails(
              channel.id,
              channel.name,
              // TODO add a proper drawable resource to android, for now using
              //      one that already exists in example app.
              icon: 'launch_background',
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    });
```